# Why does my JSpinner resize to be bigger than necessary when a SpinnerDateModel is added?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I am creating GUI form with labels and inputs. Each row has a label and then an input. One of them uses two JSpinners for input (start and end time). It is all fine and the components are all well aligned until I add a SpinnerDateModel to the spinners. Although the size of the spinner was already big enough to hold it's new contents, it widens taking up too much space (with a lot of whitespace between the end of the text and the arrows). I was originally using GridBagLayout and then tried BoxLayout (each row a panel with an X-axis BoxLayout, all on a Y-axis BoxLayout) but I get the same results. I can't find any information about this specific problem but all other advice about resizing JSpinners hasn't worked. I've tried resizing the editor component and the JFormattedTextField (including using setColumns() and checking that the columns have been changed, which they have). What else can I try?

**edit**: here is an SSCCE as requested:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;


public class SpinnerTest extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpinnerTest();

    }

    public SpinnerTest() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

        BoxLayout mainLayout = new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        setLayout(mainLayout);
        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout titleLayout = new BoxLayout(titlePanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
        titlePanel.setLayout(titleLayout);
        JPanel timePanel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout timeLayout = new BoxLayout(timePanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
        timePanel.setLayout(timeLayout);

        Calendar arb = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date initDate = arb.getTime();
        arb.add(Calendar.YEAR, -100);
        Date earliestDate = arb.getTime();
        arb.add(Calendar.YEAR, 200);
        Date latestDate = arb.getTime();
        SpinnerDateModel timeModel = new SpinnerDateModel(initDate, earliestDate,
                latestDate, Calendar.MINUTE);
        SpinnerDateModel timeModel2 = new SpinnerDateModel(initDate, earliestDate,
                latestDate, Calendar.MINUTE);

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title:");
        titleLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 16));
        titlePanel.add(titleLabel);

        JTextField titleField = new JTextField("Title");
        titleField.setColumns(10);
        titlePanel.add(titleField);

        add(titlePanel);

        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel("Time:");
        timeLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 16));
        timePanel.add(timeLabel);

        JSpinner startTime = new JSpinner(timeModel);
        JComponent editor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor) startTime.getEditor();
        JFormattedTextField ftf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) editor).getTextField();
        ftf.setColumns(5);
        ftf.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 30));
        editor.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 30));
        //System.out.println(tf.getColumns());
        startTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(startTime, "HH:mm"));
        timePanel.add(startTime);

        JSpinner endTime = new JSpinner(timeModel2);
        endTime.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(70, 20));
        JComponent editor1 = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor) endTime.getEditor();
        JFormattedTextField ftf1 = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) editor1).getTextField();
        ftf1.setColumns(5);
        ftf1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 30));
        editor1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 30));
        //System.out.println(ftf.getColumns());
        endTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(endTime, "HH:mm"));
        timePanel.add(endTime);

        add(timePanel);

        mainFrame.add(this);
        mainFrame.pack();
            mainFrame.setSize(189, mainFrame.getHeight());
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I wouldn't usually extend JPanel and then create a JFrame but the class I'm making is put in a pre-existing JFrame and extends JPanel so I'm following how mine is as close as I can.
I will emphasise BoxLayout wasn't my first choice, I changed to it knowing it listens to .setXXXSize better than most other layouts (I know I shouldn't use .setXXXSize but I didn't see how else to sort it out).
I've left in all the attempts I've tried from researching the issue so that you don't try them again.
Try using plain JSpinner constructors (and comment out code that won't work) and compare those results to what you get when you use this code in full.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your program to just use a FlowLayout so every component could be displayed at its preferred size. The formatted text field is sized to hold 5 characters. It uses a width of 11 for each character (which seems a bit excessive) so you get lots of extra space.

In your code it looks like you manually tried to control the number of columns for the formatted text field:

```
    JSpinner startTime = new JSpinner(timeModel);
    JComponent editor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor) startTime.getEditor();
    JFormattedTextField ftf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) editor).getTextField();
    ftf.setColumns(5);
    startTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(startTime, "HH:mm"));
```

The problem is you accessed the formatted text field before you changed the editor. Instead you need to set the editor before you access the formatted text field.

```
    JSpinner startTime = new JSpinner(timeModel);
    startTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(startTime, "HH:mm"));
    JComponent editor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor) startTime.getEditor();
    JFormattedTextField ftf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) editor).getTextField();
    ftf.setColumns(3);
```

I also changed the columns to 3 to decrease the amount of extra white space. Now the preferred size of the spinner is more reasonable. Test it with a FlowLayout to see what I mean.

Comment: setColumns() was one of my attempts to solve the problem, it wasn't something I originally wanted to do. I didn't need to change to FlowLayout, it works after I moved the setEditor line and reduced the columns. Thanks!